# how to accept an input command line with nodejs

Tags: node.js, command-line, electron, child-process, exp

[image]

I want to accept input from the console/terminal. That's my solution so far:

```
const expBuild = spawn("exp", ["build:ios"], { cwd: 'app' }); 

expBuild.stdout.on("data", data => { 
   console.log(`stdout: ${data.toString()}`); 
}); 

expBuild.stderr.on("data", data => { 
   console.log(`stderr: ${data.toString()}`); 
});
```

And this is what I get in the console:

[image]

Comment: Please post the code and the output as code-enclosed text in here, instead of images.

Comment: `const expBuild = spawn("exp", ["build:ios"], {
    cwd: 'app'
  });
  expBuild.stdout.on("data", data => {
    console.log(`stdout: ${data.toString()}`);
  });
  expBuild.stderr.on("data", data => {
    console.log(`stderr: ${data.toString()}`);
  });
`

how to select 

❯ Expo handles all credentials, you can still provide overrides


I will provide all the credentials and files needed, Expo does limited validation

Comment: I updated your post. The main point of asking a question is to make it as easy as possible for the readers to understand your problem. Otherwise people won't bother to answer. Check this guide on how to ask a question on SO in a good way: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: tks @Milkncookiez